# Adding multiple inline images into a feed item

Tags: trigger, images, feeditem

I've developed a custom comments object as a child of Case to support inline images for back and forth conversation between customers and support.

The last piece is to post these comments as feed items in the case console. I've seen documentation on posting inline images into feed items (I really don't understand how to implement this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_richtext_inlineimage.htm) How can I use this and is it possible to do so with multiple images and text?

My current code creates feed items but throws an error when images are included in the body of the feed item.

**Error:**

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Referenced file id is invalid, not accessible, or does not exist: [RawBody]

**Code causing the error:**

```
// iterate through comments and create a comment feed item on the associated case 
    List <FeedItem> newCommentFeedItems = new List<FeedItem>();    
    for (Case_Comments__c comments : commentsList) {
        string cbody = comments.comment__c;
        cbody = cbody.replace('<br>', '<p>&nbsp;</p>');
        FeedItem fi = new FeedItem (parentId = comments.case__c,
                                   body = cbody, 
                                   title = 'Case Comment', 
                                   isRichText = true
                                  );
     newCommentFeedItems.add(fi);

    }
```

`comments.comment__c` will sometimes contain rich text and inline images

Comment: can you post specific code snippet or area where this issue is occuring which could help you to nail down the issue

Comment: I've trimmed down my code sample and isolated the field that contains rich text images which is used for the body of the feed item to be inserted